# Set up hello world of collabora/code via docker on local

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am following [this quick start guide](https://www.collaboraoffice.com/code/quick-tryout-nextcloud-docker/) to attempt to set up collabora server using docker.

That guide uses docker directly but I'm trying to use docker-compose locally, my docker-compose.yaml file, based on the quick start guide:

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  collabora:
    image: collabora/code
    container_name: collabora
    environment:
      - extra_params=o:ssl.enable=false
    ports:
      - "9980:9980"
```

This is my attempt to translate the linked quickstart page to docker-compose.

I don't know if this is working or not. In the terminal it does appear to be:

```
sudo docker-compose build
collabora uses an image, skipping
Building with native build. Learn about native build in Compose here: https://docs.docker.com/go/compose-native-build/

sudo docker-compose up -d
Building with native build. Learn about native build in Compose here: https://docs.docker.com/go/compose-native-build/
Creating network "hz_default" with the default driver
Creating collabora ... done
```

This looks good, I think?

On the linked quickstart guide above, it says "Find out the IP address of your computer, e.g. 192.168.100.20"

I searched for 'find my ip address terminal' and typed `curl ifconfig.me` into the terminal based on my research. This returned a number of the form `123.456.789.123`

The quick start guide says :

> Note 2: Do not use localhost or 127.0.0.1 instead of IP address of your computer, because these addresses do not resolve from the containers.

My objective here it to 'get it working' on local before then using a cloud provider to host the container for use with my Nextcloud instance.

How can I tell if it's working? Gauging by the terminal output it is. But if I visit localhost:9980 there's nothing there. Or if I visit the result of curl ifconfig.me with the port, no webpage or anything appears e.g. `123.456.789.123:9980`

I realize this is a bit of a vague post but, based on the quick start guide, is my docker-compose set up sound? How can I verify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using sites like `ifconfig.me` will tell you your gateway (usually router) address. You need to know the local IP address. One way of doing it is typing `ifconfig` in the terminal, then looking for your primary network interface (ignore loopback, etc) and it will tell you the correct address. Another way is to try to find it inside your router's management interface. There are also GUI tools you can use, but it depends on your distribution and desktop environment of choice.

Regarding access to the container, you should be able to use `localhost`. You can try to use `docker inspect` to see details about the container, and `docker logs` to see its logs.